# how to get all elements lists from soap response

Tags: powershell, soap, response

I've this SOAP Response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:anow="http://tempuri.org/AnoWebservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <anow:AnoWebserviceResponse>
      <anow:result>
        <resultCode>0</resultCode>
      </anow:result>
      <anow:response>
        <DataView>
          <ERROR_CODE>NOER</ERROR_CODE>
          <SYS_FORZA>N</SYS_FORZA>
          <A>
            <B>0</B>
            <V>2016-10-06</V>
          </A>
        </DataView>
      </anow:response>
    </anow:AnoWebserviceResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Actually to extract the value of single element I'm using

```
$value=Select-Xml -XPath $XPath -Xml $SOAPResponseFile -Namespace @{ "soapenv" = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' ; "anow" = 'http://tempuri.org/AnoWebservice'}
```

I would like to extract each element name for each node.
That means that the output should be like:

```
ERROR_CODE
SYS_FORZA
B
V
```

how I can do it?

Thank you in advance

Regards

Claudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xpath = "//DataView//*"

Select-Xml -XPath $XPath -Xml $SOAPResponseFile -Namespace @{ "soapenv" = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' ; "anow" = 'http://tempuri.org/AnoWebservice'} | foreach-object {$_.node.Name}
```

Comment: Thank you @Bill Hurt it works ! it's exactly what I was looking for ;)

Comment: My `SOAPResponseFile` is empty and of type `xmldocument`. That is why it is not working for me?